# If I delete an old valid or closed post, will I lose the reputation gained from it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answer

If I delete an old valid or closed post (including question and answers), will I lose the reputation gained from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. If a post is removed, then you will lose any reputation you gained on that post. The changes may occur instantly or may not occur until your reputation is recalculated.

Comment: ... and you can [trigger a reputation recalc](http://superuser.com/reputation) manually if you need to.

Comment: @slhck: link to http://superuser.com/reputation#bottom?